# Improve posture in home

Tags: workout

I want to have a good posture. I think that if someone hasn't good he/she cans obtain it with workout. We can't have all the time or money to go to a gym or somewhere else to do our posture good. I do push up I don't know if that helps my posture I thought that helps me. What workouts could do at home to obtain good posture? push up?what?thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot at home though, as you said. You could look into resistance bands. They can help getting a better posture a lot.

It's important to first find out what's currently "wrong" with your posture, and then find exercises accordingly.

If your shoulders are rotated forward, push-ups will only make this worse, because it will strengthen the front of your upper body, and overpower the back.

Another important fact is that, a lot of possible posture "malfunctions" to call it that, are found in how you place your feet, how you move/rotate your hips, and if your core if strong enough, so keep in mind that, even though the top of your body might look like there is something wrong with your posture, the problem might be found in your hips for example.

Answer (score -3):

There's a whole bunch of info on this fairly easily available.

In general, you're going to want to focus on your core and back through things like planks, back extensions, reverse dumbbell fly's. There's a great article on [Menshealth](http://www.menshealth.com/fitness/better-posture-more-muscle) that goes over how to assess yourself and then goes into how to fix your posture.

Comment: The article may be very good, but it might not be there forever, so this answer may suddenly lose all its quality. If you provide the important excerpts here, it will remain good.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: We expect answers here to be complete, external links can be used for support but the pertinent parts should be restated (Not copy/pasted!) here. As it is, this is a low quality answer that can be deleted if it is not improved.